# WebDriver wait, different wait conditions

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using WebDriver with Java binding. I am using generic methods for element waiting. One of them is called waitByPageTitle.

Here is my definition for this method:

```
public void waitByPageTitle(WebDriver driver, String pageTitle) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, DEFAULT_IMPLICIT_WAIT);
        try {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains(pageTitle));
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

In my page objects, when a method needs to wait by a page title, I pass arguments to this method. But there are scenarios where the page title can be different based on different events.
How do I change the generic waitByPageTitle method so it accepts multiple arguments, and can wait by any one of them which ever it sees the first?

Thanks.

Comment: The generic method remains the same, before invoking you must be building the Title string to be verified, you can make sure the Title string to be verified is not same as Window Title then you can have couple of more options depending on the event and build the final Title string which will be passed for `waitForPageTitle()` method

Comment: switch from a string to a string array then use wait.until(bool).  Since it's a bool, you should be able to do a for each string in stringArray, driver.getTitle().contains(string)
http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html#until%28com.google.common.base.Predicate%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FluentWait](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) and Java [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

```
 // This method will accept any number of titles
 public void waitUntilTextChanges(WebDriver driver, String... titles) {

         new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
        .withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .until(new Predicate<WebDriver>() {

            public boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                boolean titleMatched = false;
                // Get current window title
                String windowTitle = driver.getTitle();
                for(String title : titles){
                   // Iterate through all input titles and compare with window title 
                   titleMatched = windowTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(title);
                   // If match found, exit 
                   if(titleMatched){
                      break;
                   }
                }    
                return titleMatched;
            }
        });
    }
```